# canvas 0px line drawing (html5)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

(sorry for my english)
So my question is, how can i make a 0px line?
If i call this the line stay 1px width:/

```
    imgCtx.beginPath();
        imgCtx.lineWidth = 0;
        imgCtx.fill();
    imgCtx.stroke();
```

I need just the filled section.

Comment: What is the purpose of 0px width line ?

Comment: 0px line is not a line!

Comment: becouse i need only the filled section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't call the `stroke` method.

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jessevanassen/JnsvM/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need only the filled section, then don't ask about how to get a 0px outline, ask how to only get the filled section.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "none";
```